# playframework - setting a list parameter in a custom select tag

Tags: java, scala, select, tags, playframework

I have some repetitive select tags in my html therefore I want to create a custom select tag in play  which will take as a parameter the name attribute of select (which can be done easily) and a list object through which I create option tags dynamically.

Basically I want to do something like this

```
////// custom tag stored in FormSelect.html///////
<select name="${_selectName}">
   #{list ${_options}, as: 't'}
      <option value="${t.Description}"> ${t.Description} </option> 
   #{/list}
</select>

///////calling the custom tag from another html file//////////
Type:
#{FormSelect selectName:'typ', options:types /}
Region:
#{FormSelect selectName:'reg', options:regions /}
```

**types** and **regions** variables are **Vector** and are forwarded from controller. I want **${_options}** at select tag (inside **#{list}**) to take the values of **types** and **regions**

When I excecute the above code I get this exception

```
Template execution error 

Execution error occured in template /app/views/tags/FormSelect.html. Exception raised  was MissingMethodException : No signature of method: Template_1002.$() is applicable for argument types: (Template_1002$_run_closure1_closure2) values: [Template_1002$_run_closure1_closure2@127a1d8] Possible solutions: _(java.lang.String), is(java.lang.Object), run(), run(), any(), get(java.lang.String). 


In /app/views/tags/FormSelect.html (around line 2)

1: <select name="${_selectName}">
2:     #{list ${_options}, as: 't'}
3:        <option value="${t.Description}"> ${t.Description} </option> 
4:     #{/list}
5: </select>
```

thx in advance

Comment: What's your problem? What error do you get? Have you tried this code?What are the classes in the Vectors? Their code?

Comment: ok thanks for reply,yes Ive tried the code and I get some exception, pls check the first post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
#{list ${_options}, as: 't'}
      <option value="${t.Description}"> ${t.Description} </option> 
   #{/list}
```

use:

```
#{list items:_options, as: 't'}
      <option value="${t.Description}"> ${t.Description} </option> 
#{/list}
```

That should solve your current error.

Comment: it did solve the exception but it didnt help me much,now I get an empty dropdown box, it doesnt iterate through the list

Comment: Sory I had a typo in my code so your solution works perfectly.thank you appreciate your help